# Upper and Lower bounding the $Lp$ norms of the Gaussian random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Can we find constants $K_1$ and $K_2 >0$, independent of $p$, such that for a random variable $X$ distributed standard normal satisfies:

$$K_1 \leq \dfrac{\| X \|_p}{\sqrt{p}} \leq K_2 $$ for all $p \geq 1$?

So far, my attempt, which I suspect might be computationally cumbersome and not the most efficient, is as follows.

Consider $\phi_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \{-\frac{x^2}{2}\}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to be the density of the standard gaussian and $\psi_{|X|} (x) = 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \{-\frac{x^2}{2}\}$ for $x \geq 0$ to be the density for $|X|$, that is, the half (or folded-) normal. Hence, $2 P(X>t) = P(|X| > t)$ for $t>0$.

The Mill's ratio for the Gaussian states that for $t>0$: 
$$ \phi(t) \left[\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3} \right] \leq P(X>t) \leq \phi(t) \left[\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3} + \frac{3}{t^5} \right]$$

Now recall also, by the "layer-cake representation", for $p \geq 1$:
$$E|X|^p = \int_0^{\infty} pt^{p-1} P(|X|>t) dt$$

Combining we should get:

$$\dfrac{\left(2 \int_0^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \phi(t) \left[\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3} \right] dt \right)^{1/p}}{\sqrt{p}} 
\leq \dfrac{\| X \|_p}{\sqrt{p}} 
\leq  \dfrac{\left(2 \int_0^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \phi(t)\left[\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3} + \frac{3}{t^5} \right] dt\right)^{1/p}}{\sqrt{p}} $$

Optimizing the RHS and LHS over $p\geq 1$, I expect to get $K_1$ and $K_2$ but keep running into integrals that do no converge. Is there some approximation (Stirling for Gamma Functions?) that I should be using instead?

Comment: The inequality is in expectation ? almost surely ? with high probability ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon It is to be true for all $p\geq 1$.

Comment: In dimension 1, the (integral) moments are explicit (given by the double factorial); you could then use Stirling...

Comment: It looks very much like you are reading Vershynin's book :-)

Comment: you have what you need around page 26 of that reference.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for pointing that book out. I didn't this is from there. I saw my officemate working on this problem and it just stuck with me.

Comment: What about the lower bound?

Comment: I guess the lower bound works with $K_1 = 1$